# When I parse a large XML sitemap on Beautifulsoup in Python, it only parses part of the file

Tags: python-3.x, xml, beautifulsoup, sitemap

I have written code that pulls out URLs of a very large sitemap xml file (10mb) using Beautiful Soup, and it works exactly how I want it, but it only seems to do a small amount of the overall file. This is my code:

```
`sitemap = "sitemap1.xml"
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import lxml
content = []

with open(sitemap, "r") as file:
    # Read each line in the file, readlines() returns a list of lines
    content = file.readlines()
    # Combine the lines in the list into a string
    content = "".join(content)
    bs_content = bs(content, "xml")

result = bs_content.find_all("loc")

for result in result:
    print(result.text)
`
```

I have changed my IDE to allow for larger files, it just seems to start the process at a random point towards the end of the XML file and only extracts from there on.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to say I ended up sorting this out. I used the read XML function in pandas and it worked well. The original XML file was corrupted.

... I also realised that the console was just printing from a certain point because it's such a large file, and it was still actually processing the whole file.

Sorry about this - I'm new :)