# Can't supply list of links to "concurrent.futures" instead of one link at a time

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, concurrent.futures

I've created a script using "concurrent.futures" to scrape some datapoints from a website. The script is working flawlessly in the way I'm currently using it. However, I wish to supply the links as a list to the "future_to_url" block instead of one link at a time.

This is currently how I'm trying.

```
links = [
    'first link',
    'second link',
    'third link',
]

def get_links(link):
    while True:
        res = requests.get(link,headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
        for item in soup.select("[data-testid='serp-ia-card'] [class*='businessName'] a[href^='/biz/'][name]"):
            shop_name = item.get_text(strip=True)
            shop_link = item.get('href')
            yield shop_name,shop_link
        
        next_page = soup.select_one("a.next-link[aria-label='Next']")
        if not next_page: return
        link = next_page.get("href")

def get_content(shop_name,shop_link):
    res = requests.get(shop_link,headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
    try:
        phone = soup.select_one("p:-soup-contains('Phone number') + p").get_text(strip=True)
    except (AttributeError,TypeError): phone = ""
    return shop_name,shop_link,phone

if __name__ == '__main__':
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=6) as executor:
            
            """
            would like to supply the list of links to 
            the "future_to_url" block instead of one link at a time
            """

            for link in links:

                future_to_url = {executor.submit(get_content, *elem): elem for elem in get_links(link)}
                for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
                    shop_name,shop_link,phone = future.result()[0],future.result()[1],future.result()[2]
                    print(shop_name,shop_link,phone)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is `executor.map` where you can pass an iterable.

I've simplified your code since you're not providing the links, but that should give you the general idea.

Here's how:

```py
import concurrent.futures
from itertools import chain

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

links = [
    'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup?sort=Newest&filters=NoAnswers&uqlId=30134',
    'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x+web-scraping?sort=Newest&filters=NoAnswers&uqlId=27838',
]

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36',
}


def get_links(source_url: str) -> list:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(source_url, headers=headers).text, "html.parser")
    return [
        (a.getText(), f"https://stackoverflow.com{a['href']}") for a
        in soup.select(".s-post-summary--content .s-post-summary--content-title a")
    ]


def get_content(content_data: tuple) -> str:
    question, url = content_data
    user = (
        BeautifulSoup(s.get(url, headers=headers).text, "html.parser")
        .select_one(".user-info .user-details a")
    )
    return f"{question}\n{url}\nAsked by: {user.getText()}"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with requests.Session() as s:
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=6) as executor:
            results = executor.map(
                get_content,
                chain.from_iterable(executor.map(get_links, links)),
            )
            for result in results:
                print(result)
```

This prints all question titles and who asked it. For the sake of the example I'm visiting the question page to get the user name.

```
Can't use find after find_all while making a loop for parsing
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74570141/cant-use-find-after-find-all-while-making-a-loop-for-parsing
Asked by: wasdy
The results are different from the VS code when using AWS lambda.(selenium,BeautifulSoup)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74557551/the-results-are-different-from-the-vs-code-when-using-aws-lambda-selenium-beaut
Asked by: user20588340
Beautiful on Python not as expected
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74554271/beautiful-on-python-not-as-expected
Asked by: Woody1193
Selenium bypass login
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74551814/selenium-bypass-login
Asked by: Python12492
Tags not found with BeautifulSoup parsing
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74551202/tags-not-found-with-beautifulsoup-parsing
Asked by: Reem Aljunaid
When I parse a large XML sitemap on Beautifulsoup in Python, it only parses part of the file
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74543726/when-i-parse-a-large-xml-sitemap-on-beautifulsoup-in-python-it-only-parses-part
Asked by: JS0NBOURNE
How can I solve Http Error 308: Permanent Redirect in Data Crawling?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74541173/how-can-i-solve-http-error-308-permanent-redirect-in-data-crawling
Asked by: Illubith

and more ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, baduker, for your awesome solution.